# Out of scope question with ongoing discussion

Tags: discussion, scope

This pertains to: [How do I store data with a query that's approximated ?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/how-do-i-store-data-with-a-query-thats-a-approximated)

I felt that the question as stated was too localized, and invited the OP to generalize because I thought there was a valid question lurking within. But that hasn't happened, and the ensuing discussion seems clearly out of scope. Any thoughts on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question sounds like it fits more within the scope of MetaOptimize.com/qa or stats.stackoverflow.com (which I cannot tell apart). Perhaps leave the question for a day or two to see whether it improves. If it doesn't then suggest to the author to repost on one of the above mentioned sites.

Comment: I felt like the OP was given enough time already though.

Comment: Then skip to step two.

Comment: I agree. If a question might be possible to fix, but OP does not react to comments within a day or two, then we can close the question. In general, I think it is very strange to post questions and not check within 24 hours if there are any comments or answers.

Comment: maybe they are not *real* questions :).